# Transforming list of objects into nested UL not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to transform a list of objects that I get through ajax into a nested ul for a category menu. After looking on this site, I found a PHP function and transformed it into javascript.

Unfortunately it's not working:

```
function has_children(data, id) {
    for(a=0; a<data.length; a++) {
        if (data[a].ParentID == id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function renderCategoryTree(data, parent) {
    result = "<ul>";
    for(index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
        if (data[index].ParentID == parent) {
            result = result + "<li>" + data[index].Name;
            if (has_children(data, data[index].ID)) 
                result = result + renderCategoryTree(data, data[index].ID);
            result = result + "</li>";
        }
    }
    result = result + "</ul>";

    return result;
}

var stuff= [ { ID: 1, ParentID: 0, Name: 'Development' },
{ ID: 2, ParentID: 0, Name: 'Databases' },
{ ID: 3, ParentID: 0, Name: 'Systems' },
{ ID: 4, ParentID: 1, Name: 'java' },
{ ID: 5, ParentID: 1, Name: 'c++' },
{ ID: 6, ParentID: 1, Name: 'python' },
{ ID: 7, ParentID: 1, Name: 'ruby' },
{ ID: 8, ParentID: 2, Name: 'mysql' },
{ ID: 9, ParentID: 2, Name: 'oracle' },
{ ID: 10, ParentID: 2, Name: 'sqlite' },
{ ID: 11, ParentID: 3, Name: 'linux' },
{ ID: 12, ParentID: 3, Name: 'windows' } ];

  alert(renderCategoryTree(stuff, 0));
```

The rendering stops at "ruby". I think the problem is with the way javascript typing works but I'm not sure. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your loop counters are global. So if you write

```
for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++) {
```

instead of

```
for(a=0; a<data.length; a++) {
```

and

```
for(var index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
```

instead of

```
for(index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
```

it will work.

Comment: You are right. I answered the question the same time as you. You'll get the right answer because you took the time and effort. Thanks!

Comment: And the demo http://jsfiddle.net/bLE8y/
Good demonstration why one must always remember about `var` keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem: because javascript variables survive nested function calls, you have to use var to make them local.

Just adding var to for index declaration worked!